# Dynamic editable table/grid generation with postback in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, postback

I need to generate a table in MVC that can have a variable set of horizontal columns (years). I need to render a textbox in each cell and I need to postback the values to a action method. I have seen examples where the editable cells are generated but the columns are fixed (using partials). I have also seen examples where the table can be rendered with dynamic columns but without the editable cells/textboxes. Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: can you point us to links to the editable cells with fixed columns and editable dynamic columns , it would be of great help.

Comment: @Thunder, this is the article I used. [link](http://shazwazza.com/post/HtmlHelper-Table-methods.aspx) Its been a long time since I worked on that code, and it needs serious refactoring but I would be happy to send on what i have. Its a bit verbose for posting here

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating the dynamic table with a textbox in each cell with an onchange action to send the data via ajax to the controller for the update.

You will probably need to pass a multidimensional array within the model and use it to create and load your table.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but It is a batch update. All cells will be editable and shall be submitted to the user in one postback

Answer (score 0):

The question is though how are you expecting to handle this on the server side?
If you name them all sequentially and know the # of columns ahead of time the model binder CAN bind to a list for you if they are all named in the appropriate format. Do you want to generate the list from a model or some other method?

Phil Haack covers how the naming format is, although the EditorFor will handle this automatically in some cases. If it doesnt work in yours, simply naming them in this scheme should work.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Thanks Adam yes I am binding to a list and I could name them all sequentially. I will always know the number of columns. The bound objects have only 4 properties, id, year, category and value( all ints). I need to have a row in the table for each type and a column for each category. Categories are fixed. its the year that must be dynamic. I have seen all the list bindin articles out there but none cater for a situation where the columns are dynamic and cells are textboxes that need to be posted back